# unable to install mcafee-epo from azure devops

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pip, azure-devops, mcafee

When I run command 'pip install mcafee-epo' from azure devops, I get below error.

Script contents:
pip install mcafee-epo

```
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]Collecting mcafee-epo
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/mcafee-epo/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/mcafee-epo/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/mcafee-epo/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/mcafee-epo/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)': /simple/mcafee-epo/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/mcafee-epo/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/mcafee-epo/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:719)'),)) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mcafee-epo (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mcafee-epo
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Hosted Agent or Self Hosted Agent?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Hosted one

Comment: Can you share your pipeline? which Hosted agent do you use?